# ¿Cómo hago para que Jupyter Notebook me reconozca HTML en una celda en Ubuntu?

Tags: html, ubuntu, jupyter, anaconda, ipython

Ocurre que desde la primera línea de código en HTML, las celdas no me lo reconocen, dicen por ejemplo:

```
File "<ipython-input-13-e9627d847514>", line 1
    <ul style="font-size:100%; line-height : 25px;">COMENTARIOS:</ul>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

He visto que hay quienes logran "correr" HTML en Jupyter, pero no he sabido cómo, y sospecho que hay algo en Ubuntu que falta para poder hacerlo, valga aclarar que trabajo en Ubuntu. ¿qué necesitaría para correr HMTL en Jupiter Notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Tenés que cambiar el tipo de la celda a de `Code` a `Markdown` tocando la tecla m con la celda seleccionada o desde el menu superior.

Fijate en el siguiente ejemplo. El tipo de las primeras dos celdas es Markdown y al ejectuarlas (la primera no está ejecutada pero la segunda si) se ve como un título. Si el tipo de la celda es Code, pasa como en el último caso.

[image: Ejemplo]